# How to develop dynamic bundle load

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I just created a new project from scratch with [AngularJs SPA Template](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5af151b2-9ed2-4809-bfe8-27566bfe7d83). In here I want to have multiple bundles so I can change them at will. I've added 2 new bundles with:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/contactsBundle").Include(
                "~/scripts/Controllers/ContactController.js"));
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/aboutBundle").Include(
                "~/scripts/Controllers/AboutController.js"));
```

Then I wanted to be able to load those bundle dynamically so when I go the about page to load the `aboutBundle` and `contactBundle` when I go to contact page.

I've tried to add this on layout page the problem is that only the bundles I load first time will get the correct bundle so if I will go on about page first then on contact page only the `aboutBundle` will be loaded.

I've also tried to set the bundle into the each view but the controller loads to late and the information on page is not displayed as expected.

My question is how can I load dynamic the bundles and not add all the js files on the first load?

**Edit:**
I've tried to load in the layout like this:

```
@Scripts.Render(Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["bundle"].ToString())
```

Comment: These files are  cached by browsers so why not load them all together when the browser hits the first page.  If you try to load at controller level, the first visit may be erratic due to the time it will take to load JS in browser compared to time the browser will take to render the page ( but I am not sure about this because if JS is included on the top of the html rendered by the view, the browser will load the js first).

Comment: isn't the load 2 much for the first time?

Comment: Not unless they are huge huge files and even then they are going to be loaded eventually. It is best to give it 300 millisecond more at the beginning than later (from user experience view point).

Comment: @AllenKing ok, thank you we will give it a try like this for the first time. If you know a solution for this please post it :)

Comment: Can you post how you are loading the bundle in View?  To my knowledge, when HTML is rendered in the browser based on the view returned from the controller and if JS is included, it should be loaded before rendering of HTML.